# layout elements position problem

Tags: android

i've created an application for galaxy S..so i'm using 3.7 inch(resolution 320x480) layout for my xml files. The app is working perfectly on the phone. When using the same app in HTC wildfire whose resolution is 240x320 the graphics are out of position. I know the reason is obvious that I'm developing app in 3.7WVGA so graphics will not be compatible for QVGA.

Is the only solution is to create different versions of app on the basis of devices?? or is there a universal solution which i can implement so that the app will run without graphical repositioning on all the devices having different screen sizes and different resolution support??

please help me...coz i dnt really know the answer....and thank you in advance

Comment: May I suggest the question be asked on http://android.stackexchange.com/ coz that is specific to android.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with it, use linear layouts and position things by weight. That way the ratios will stay the same and the same general appearance will hold.

Comment: alright....can u xplain me how to position things by weight...thank you for responding

Comment: i used relative layout and it's close to perfect..thnkx anyways

Comment: sorry i didnt get back about the weights. I can explain if you want.
If you want true perfection, you can always create two different layouts (with the same name) with all id's the same. That way android will decide which layout to use at runtime. Check out "Alternative Resources": http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html.